# Segmentation fault 11 fix?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to make an app where you push a button as many times as possible in a certain amount of time for points. I've been building it and running it on my iPhone daily for the past week or so, but now all of the sudden Xcode is giving me and error "segmentation fault 11". I have removed code that I added, removed things from the storyboard, and even reinstalled Xcode, but nothing has fixed the problem. There's articles and videos on how to fix it, but none of them seem to work for me.

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import AudioToolbox


// PlaySounds
class PlaySounds {

    private var soundID: SystemSoundID = 0

    public init(named name: String) {
        if let soundURL = soundURL(forName: name) {
            let status = AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundURL as CFURL, &soundID)
            if status != noErr {
                print("Unable to create sound at URL: '\(name)'")
                soundID = 0
            }
        }
    }

    public func play() {
        if soundID != 0 {
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID)
        }
    }

    private func soundURL(forName name: String) -> URL? {

        let fileExtensions = ["m4a", "wav", "mp3", "aac", "adts", "aif", "aiff", "aifc", "caf", "mp4"]

        for fileExtention in fileExtensions {
            if let soundURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: name, withExtension: fileExtention) {
                return soundURL
            }
        }
        print("Unable to find sound file with name '\(name)'")
        return nil
    }

    deinit {
        if soundID != 0 {
            AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(soundID)
        }
    }
}

// ViewController
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let startTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.4, target: self, selector: #selector(UIMenuController.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    let XDSound = PlaySounds(named: "XDDDDDDD")

    @IBAction func playButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        XDSound.play()

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

And the error code:

```
CompileSwift normal arm64 /Users/aaa/Desktop/XD/XD/XD/ViewController.swift
    cd /Users/aaa/Desktop/XD/XD
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -c -primary-file /Users/aaa/Desktop/XD/XD/XD/ViewController.swift /Users/aaa/Desktop/XD/XD/XD/AppDelegate.swift -target arm64-apple-ios10.0 -Xllvm -aarch64-use-tbi -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk -I /Users/aaa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XD-glogqttrbkyynngrdofevqkflfyf/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F /Users/aaa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XD-glogqttrbkyynngrdofevqkflfyf/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -enable-testing -g -module-cache-path /Users/aaa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -D DEBUG -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc -I/Users/aaa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XD-glogqttrbkyynngrdofevqkflfyf/Build/Intermediates/XD.build/Debug-iphoneos/XD.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/aaa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XD-glogqttrbkyynngrdofevqkflfyf/Build/Intermediates/XD.build/Debug-iphoneos/XD.build/XD-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/aaa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XD-glogqttrbkyynngrdofevqkflfyf/Build/Intermediates/XD.build/Debug-iphoneos/XD.build/XD-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/aaa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XD-glogqttrbkyynngrdofevqkflfyf/Build/Intermediates/XD.build/Debug-iphoneos/XD.build/XD-all-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/aaa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XD-glogqttrbkyynngrdofevqkflfyf/Build/Intermediates/XD.build/Debug-iphoneos/XD.build/XD-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/aaa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XD-glogqttrbkyynngrdofevqkflfyf/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/include -Xcc -I/Users/aaa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XD-glogqttrbkyynngrdofevqkflfyf/Build/Intermediates/XD.build/Debug-iphoneos/XD.build/DerivedSources/arm64 -Xcc -I/Users/aaa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XD-glogqttrbkyynngrdofevqkflfyf/Build/Intermediates/XD.build/Debug-iphoneos/XD.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -working-directory/Users/aaa/Desktop/XD/XD -emit-module-doc-path /Users/aaa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XD-glogqttrbkyynngrdofevqkflfyf/Build/Intermediates/XD.build/Debug-iphoneos/XD.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ViewController~partial.swiftdoc -Onone -module-name XD -emit-module-path /Users/aaa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XD-glogqttrbkyynngrdofevqkflfyf/Build/Intermediates/XD.build/Debug-iphoneos/XD.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ViewController~partial.swiftmodule -serialize-diagnostics-path /Users/aaa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XD-glogqttrbkyynngrdofevqkflfyf/Build/Intermediates/XD.build/Debug-iphoneos/XD.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ViewController.dia -emit-dependencies-path /Users/aaa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XD-glogqttrbkyynngrdofevqkflfyf/Build/Intermediates/XD.build/Debug-iphoneos/XD.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ViewController.d -emit-reference-dependencies-path /Users/aaa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XD-glogqttrbkyynngrdofevqkflfyf/Build/Intermediates/XD.build/Debug-iphoneos/XD.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ViewController.swiftdeps -o /Users/aaa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XD-glogqttrbkyynngrdofevqkflfyf/Build/Intermediates/XD.build/Debug-iphoneos/XD.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ViewController.o

0  swift                    0x000000010bf6bb6d PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) + 45
1  swift                    0x000000010bf6b5b6 SignalHandler(int) + 470
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fffa9fdebba _sigtramp + 26
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff568ee500 _sigtramp + 2895182176
4  swift                    0x000000010944b00f llvm::Value* llvm::function_ref<llvm::Value* (swift::irgen::IRGenFunction&, llvm::Constant*)>::callback_fn<getTypeMetadataAccessFunction(swift::irgen::IRGenModule&, swift::CanType, swift::ForDefinition_t)::$_3>(long, swift::irgen::IRGenFunction&, llvm::Constant*) + 255
5  swift                    0x000000010944974a swift::irgen::emitLazyCacheAccessFunction(swift::irgen::IRGenModule&, llvm::Function*, llvm::GlobalVariable*, llvm::function_ref<llvm::Value* (swift::irgen::IRGenFunction&)> const&) + 1194
6  swift                    0x000000010944b2cc getTypeMetadataAccessFunction(swift::irgen::IRGenModule&, swift::CanType, swift::ForDefinition_t, llvm::function_ref<llvm::Value* (swift::irgen::IRGenFunction&, llvm::Constant*)>&&) + 300
7  swift                    0x000000010944ae45 emitCallToTypeMetadataAccessFunction(swift::irgen::IRGenFunction&, swift::CanType, swift::ForDefinition_t) + 117
8  swift                    0x00000001094498dc swift::irgen::IRGenFunction::emitTypeMetadataRef(swift::CanType) + 108
9  swift                    0x000000010948707d void llvm::function_ref<void (swift::irgen::GenericRequirement)>::callback_fn<(anonymous namespace)::EmitPolymorphicArguments::emit(swift::CanTypeWrapper<swift::SILFunctionType>, llvm::ArrayRef<swift::Substitution>, swift::irgen::WitnessMetadata*, swift::irgen::Explosion&)::$_14>(long, swift::irgen::GenericRequirement) + 861
10 swift                    0x000000010947c9e1 (anonymous namespace)::PolymorphicConvention::enumerateRequirements(llvm::function_ref<void (swift::irgen::GenericRequirement)> const&) + 129
11 swift                    0x0000000109486bdb swift::irgen::emitPolymorphicArguments(swift::irgen::IRGenFunction&, swift::CanTypeWrapper<swift::SILFunctionType>, swift::CanTypeWrapper<swift::SILFunctionType>, llvm::ArrayRef<swift::Substitution>, swift::irgen::WitnessMetadata*, swift::irgen::Explosion&) + 459
12 swift                    0x00000001094e34f5 (anonymous namespace)::IRGenSILFunction::visitFullApplySite(swift::FullApplySite) + 2997
13 swift                    0x00000001094ce268 swift::irgen::IRGenModule::emitSILFunction(swift::SILFunction*) + 9080
14 swift                    0x00000001093f2601 swift::irgen::IRGenerator::emitGlobalTopLevel() + 1329
15 swift                    0x00000001094b3fcb performIRGeneration(swift::IRGenOptions&, swift::ModuleDecl*, swift::SILModule*, llvm::StringRef, llvm::LLVMContext&, swift::SourceFile*, unsigned int) + 1259
16 swift                    0x00000001093821c7 performCompile(swift::CompilerInstance&, swift::CompilerInvocation&, llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, int&, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 23687
17 swift                    0x000000010937a265 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 17029
18 swift                    0x000000010933782d main + 8685
19 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fffa9dd2255 start + 1
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -c -primary-file /Users/aaa/Desktop/XD/XD/XD/ViewController.swift /Users/aaa/Desktop/XD/XD/XD/AppDelegate.swift -target arm64-apple-ios10.0 -Xllvm -aarch64-use-tbi -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk -I /Users/aaa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XD-glogqttrbkyynngrdofevqkflfyf/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F /Users/aaa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XD-glogqttrbkyynngrdofevqkflfyf/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -enable-testing -g -module-cache-path /Users/aaa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -D DEBUG -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc -I/Users/aaa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XD-glogqttrbkyynngrdofevqkflfyf/Build/Intermediates/XD.build/Debug-iphoneos/XD.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/aaa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XD-glogqttrbkyynngrdofevqkflfyf/Build/Intermediates/XD.build/Debug-iphoneos/XD.build/XD-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/aaa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XD-glogqttrbkyynngrdofevqkflfyf/Build/Intermediates/XD.build/Debug-iphoneos/XD.build/XD-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/aaa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XD-glogqttrbkyynngrdofevqkflfyf/Build/Intermediates/XD.build/Debug-iphoneos/XD.build/XD-all-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/aaa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XD-glogqttrbkyynngrdofevqkflfyf/Build/Intermediates/XD.build/Debug-iphoneos/XD.build/XD-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/aaa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XD-glogqttrbkyynngrdofevqkflfyf/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/include -Xcc -I/Users/aaa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XD-glogqttrbkyynngrdofevqkflfyf/Build/Intermediates/XD.build/Debug-iphoneos/XD.build/DerivedSources/arm64 -Xcc -I/Users/aaa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XD-glogqttrbkyynngrdofevqkflfyf/Build/Intermediates/XD.build/Debug-iphoneos/XD.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -working-directory/Users/aaa/Desktop/XD/XD -emit-module-doc-path /Users/aaa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XD-glogqttrbkyynngrdofevqkflfyf/Build/Intermediates/XD.build/Debug-iphoneos/XD.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ViewController~partial.swiftdoc -Onone -module-name XD -emit-module-path /Users/aaa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XD-glogqttrbkyynngrdofevqkflfyf/Build/Intermediates/XD.build/Debug-iphoneos/XD.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ViewController~partial.swiftmodule -serialize-diagnostics-path /Users/aaa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XD-glogqttrbkyynngrdofevqkflfyf/Build/Intermediates/XD.build/Debug-iphoneos/XD.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ViewController.dia -emit-dependencies-path /Users/aaa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XD-glogqttrbkyynngrdofevqkflfyf/Build/Intermediates/XD.build/Debug-iphoneos/XD.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ViewController.d -emit-reference-dependencies-path /Users/aaa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XD-glogqttrbkyynngrdofevqkflfyf/Build/Intermediates/XD.build/Debug-iphoneos/XD.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ViewController.swiftdeps -o /Users/aaa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XD-glogqttrbkyynngrdofevqkflfyf/Build/Intermediates/XD.build/Debug-iphoneos/XD.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ViewController.o 
1.  While emitting IR SIL function @_TFC2XD14ViewControllercfT7nibNameGSqSS_6bundleGSqCSo6Bundle__S0_ for 'init' at /Users/aaa/Desktop/XD/XD/XD/ViewController.swift:56:40
```

It says on the bottom of the error "swift:56:40" which I think means the 40th character of the 56th line, but all that's there is the opening bracket for the ViewController. Help?

Comment: I pasted your code into a playground in Xcode 8, and got this error immediately: "The LLDB RPC server has crashed. The crash log is located in ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports and has a prefix 'lldb-roc-server'. Please file a bug and attach the most recent crash log." So it seems you found a bug with the LLDB debugger!

Answer (score 0):

The line to initialize the timer causes the error.

You can't call target/action methods on the top level of a class.

Either declare the variable as implicit unwrapped optional

```
var startTimer : Timer!
```

and initialize it in `viewDidLoad`

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      startTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.4, 
                                              target: self, 
                                            selector: #selector(UIMenuController.update), 
                                            userInfo: nil, 
                                             repeats: true)
  }
```

or declare the variable as `lazy` with a closure

```
lazy var startTimer : Timer = {
    return Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 4.0, target: self, selector: #selector(update), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}()
```

and call it to start the timer

```
let _ = startTimer
```

Comment: I typed his code into the playground again and it did not crash. The compiler is not complaining about the timer or anything else. Weird.

Comment: Thanks! I had a timer in there but it wasn't working so I removed it... thought I got rid of all the code. I need to open my eyes!